# Verifying the signature of Alexa request

Tags: signature, alexa-skills-kit, verification

I am currently building a webservice that should handle Alexa voice intents. The HTTP request I get from Alexa must be verified by checking a signature, as described in the documentation (see below for excerpt).
Various info:
    certificate chain file:https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-5.pem
    Original received signature for the above example signature:

```
LqhhuCKwBRVucGS1MHS2yf3jKMmpm10cuImDnK0bC8lQHLfCbMukdHhvulWH4SAypXqgAk3y81G0CRS4NIG+oLnTB3PfeHb70yS8WdSFflKd/NlTc/2Rr1c5pCdpZ9C1LtNmsa/pSafTbSt4RDhmQ8XtKVCw6twhTsebS6om6/ggom95z3m1Zi4k4SkLKRQGvq18+sJHcsADKHrLO735FQ3CNrIVfS76UMXkROlJ9oSEBa9KpqSONffdVe7DDBGTGF4CLjfoSDDBjQ1nCQ0THxljUdTZ2kp4cYn1qkXJfCPoLB2+75O6Cndf+BMP9+gWd20Rl5GV44KLY9ezwEmYpA==
```

Excerpt from the Alexa documentation:

> Checking the Signature of the Request
>
> Requests sent by Alexa provide the information you need to verify the
>   signature in the HTTP headers:
>
> SignatureCertChainUrl Signature To validate the signature:
>
> Verify the URL specified by the SignatureCertChainUrl header value on
>   the request to ensure that it matches the format used by Amazon. See
>   Verifying the Signature Certificate URL. Download the PEM-encoded
>   X.509 certificate chain that Alexa used to sign the message as
>   specified by the SignatureCertChainUrl header value on the request.
>   This chain is provided at runtime so that the certificate may be
>   updated periodically, so your web service should be resilient to
>   different URLs with different content. This certificate chain is
>   composed of, in order, (1) the Amazon signing certificate and (2) one
>   or more additional certificates that create a chain of trust to a root
>   certificate authority (CA) certificate. To confirm the validity of the
>   signing certificate, perform the following checks: The signing
>   certificate has not expired (examine both the Not Before and Not After
>   dates) The domain echo-api.amazon.com is present in the Subject
>   Alternative Names (SANs) section of the signing certificate All
>   certificates in the chain combine to create a chain of trust to a
>   trusted root CA certificate Once you have determined that the signing
>   certificate is valid, extract the public key from it. Base64-decode
>   the Signature header value on the request to obtain the encrypted
>   signature. Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate
>   to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.
>   Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to
>   produce the derived hash value Compare the asserted hash value and
>   derived hash values to ensure that they match

Then I used the verify method in class `SkillRequestSignatureVerifier` provided by Alexa SDK, but it didn't work.
Which decoding way should I use to realize what it says:

> Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt
>   the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.

And he say :

> Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to
>   produce the derived hash value.

But I don't find it. Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: any update on this ?